# Is there a way to have multiple instances of a model embedded into a single model field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, mongodb-query, foreign-keys

I know the foreign key concept,Djongo Array field  , however is there an alternative?
The issue with the foreign key concept is that I would need to make multiple hits to the database and the issue with Array field is the lack of information and the errors emerging without a known solution.
What I would like to do basically is in fact add multiple instances of a model say comments to a single field in another model but I would like to embed it rather than creating a new table for comments which I tried using an abstract model however it did not work out.
I would like to know any alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreign keys, and to avoid making separate query for every related record you can extract them all at once using prefetch_related - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related :

> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

Code example:

```
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()


# Somewhere else, fetch posts together with related comments:
# It will take 2 requests in total 
# - one to fetch posts, another to fetch all related comments
for post in Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('comment_set'):
    print([c.text for c in post.comment_set.all()])
```